# Prerender SPA plugin laravel mix with vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, prerender

I have a vuejs application which is integrated with the wordpress API and pulls the data using Axios.

Here is my build script

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your theme. By default, we are compiling the Sass file for the theme
 | as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.setPublicPath('dist')
   .js('src/app.js', 'scripts/')
   .extract([
      'jquery',
      'axios',
      'babel-polyfill',
      'lodash',
      'tether',
      'vue'
   ])
   .version();
```

I am looking to integrate the prerender tool for server side rendering to help with SEO. Unfortunately I am unsure as to where to begin. I have tried using something like this in here

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  // ... your other options ... 
  // Ensure asynchronous chunks are injected into <head> 
  inject: 'head',
  // Ensure chunks are evaluated in correct order 
  chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
})
```

I keep getting build errors as I am sure I am doing it wrong. I an looking for some guidance on what I should be looking out for.

Thanks